# Live updates on website - 1 ajax per second is bad practice?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, api, architecture, software-design

I have a website where each user can have several **orders**. Each order has its own **status**. A background process, keeps updating the status of each order as necessary. I want to inform the user in real-time on the status of his orders. As such, I have developed an API endpoint that returns all the orders of a given user.
On the client-side, I've developed a React component that displays the orders, and then every second an AJAX request is performed to the API to get all the orders and their status, and then React will auto-update if necessary.

Is making 1 AJAX call per second to get all orders of a user a bad practice? What are other strategies that I can do?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. You can use Socket to accomplish this. Take a look at [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/)

Edit: My point is, why to use AJAX to simulate a task that can be done with a feature that is designed for it? Sockets are just made to do this kind of thing.

Imagine if your user lost internet connection for example. With Socket.IO you can handle this very nicely. But I don't think it will be that easy with AJAX.

And thinking about scalability, Socket.IO is designed to be performant with whatever transport it settles on. The way it gracefully degrades based on what connection is possible is great and means your server will be overloaded as little as possible while still reaching as wide an audience as it can.

AJAX will do the trick, but it's not the best design.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Why is it bad practice?

Comment: socket is better because it establishes a connection based on event emits

Comment: hey @Ivan, just edited my answer talking about why I would go with sockets and not ajax in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no one solution fit all answer for this question.

First off, this is not a chat app, a delay of less than 1 second doesn't change the user experience by much, if any.

So that leaves us with technical reasons, it really depends on many factors:

How many users you have (overall load), how many concurrent users are waiting for their orders, what infrastructure you are using, do you have other important things to build or you just want to spend more time coding things for fun?

If you have a handful of users, there is nothing wrong with querying once per second, it's easy, less maintenance overhead, and you said you have it coded already.

If you have dozens or more of concurrent users waiting for the status it's probably best to use Websockets.

In terms of infrastructure, too many websockets are expensive (some cloud hosting have limits on the number of sockets), so keep that in mind if you want to go with that route.